# Windows file share access permission by computer

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing

Here's what I want to happen:

- User A logged into computer in the "Laptops" group: access denied to file share
- The same User A logged into computer in the "Terminal Servers" group: access granted to file share

This is an AD domain at the 2003 functional level, with a 2003 DC and file server. I know it's kind of weak security  (i.e. they can sign into the TS and email it to themselves), but it will only be a supplement to additional access control rules. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think that's possible. File/Folder access isn't predicated/determined by which computer a user is logged on to, it's determined by the ACE's on the ACL of the resource being secured (files and folders), which are granted to users and groups.

Comment: I figured. Oh well, can't hurt to ask. If you want to make it an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... I don't think that's possible. File/Folder access isn't predicated/determined by which computer a user is logged on to, it's determined by the ACE's on the ACL of the resource being secured (files and folders), which are granted to users and groups